# Diagonalizable Matrices - Eigenvector test

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a simple question that I need to clarify, I am trying to  find if there is a change of co-ordinates existing which would make a given matrix diagonal.

I was testing for this by computing all the eigenvectors for a matrix and checking if they are linearly independent, if so then a change of co-ordinates exists if not then I'm not sure, that is where my problem arises,

What is the concrete test for whether a matrix is Diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to determine if an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable.

1. Compute the distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_r$ of $A$.
2. For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ define the *eigenspace associated to $\lambda$* as $E_\lambda=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(\lambda\cdot I-A)$.
3. For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ compute $\dim E_\lambda$.
4. If $\sum_{j=1}^r\dim E_{\lambda_j}=n$, then $A$ is diagonalizable. If $\sum_{j=1}^r\dim E_{\lambda_j}\neq n$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Note: If $r=n$, then $A$ is automatically diagonalizable.

Comment: I understand all bar one element of your answer, this may be a stupid question, but what does $r$ represent?

Comment: The number of eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thank you sir, that cleared everything up perfectly!